# How do i filter an array inside of a array of objects value

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const data = [
  { name: "name1", option: "option1", category: [{ id: 1, value: "national" }] },
  { name: "name2", option: "option2", category: [{ id: 2, value: "international" }] },
  { name: "name3", option: "option3", category: [{ id: 3, value: "sports" }] },
  { name: "name4", option: "option4", category: [{ id: 4, value: "entertainment" }] },
];
```

I would like to filter of this array **value** of **category**
// // console.log(data);

```js
const result = data.filter(e => {
  return e.category.filter(b => b.value === 'national')
})
```

// I want output like bellow

```js
{ name: "name1", option: "option1", category: [{ id: 1, value: "national" }] },
```

Comment: What's the final result you are looking for and what have you tried that is not working ?

Comment: Please show example of expected output.

Comment: I have change my question plz

Comment: `data.filter(e => e.category.some(b => b.value === 'national'))`…? Keeps all `data` items that have *any* 'national' value in `category`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify the code for multiple arrays in category:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "name1", option: "option1", category: [{ id: 1, value: "national" }, {id: 1, value: "mundial" }]},
  { name: "name2", option: "option2", category: [{ id: 2, value: "international" }] },
  { name: "name3", option: "option3", category: [{ id: 3, value: "sports" }] },
  { name: "name4", option: "option4", category: [{ id: 4, value: "entertainment" }] },
];

var result = data.filter(x => x.category.some(y => y.value == "mundial"));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: But i can have multiple national value

Comment: i modify the code, maybe this is what you are looking for